# VB.net Sybase 12 SAadapter commands

Tags: sql, vb.net, sybase

THis is the code I am using to connect to my sybase database:

```
 Dim DefConn As New SAConnection("UID=" + SQLUser + ";PWD=" + SQLPass + ";ENG=" + Database_Txt.Text + ";LINKS=tcpip(host=" + Server_Txt.Text + ";DoBroadcast=none)")
        Dim Executer As New SADataAdapter(SQLStatement_Txt.Text, DefConn)
        Dim DataSet As New DataSet
        DefConn.Open()
        Executer.Fill(DataSet, "1")
        Results_DtaGridView.DataSource = DataSet.Tables("1")
        ResultsPrivate_DtaGridView.DataSource = DataSet.Tables("1")
        DefConn.Close()
```

This works when i use "select * from table", but for some reason when i try and run commands like "Show tables" or "Describe table "table name", they do not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you create (`New`) so many objects, only to throw them away/never use them?

Comment: I fixed that, any ideas on the sa issue?